# How to target a specific element in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a nav menu where if a list item is clicked it will change the class name.

This is the code I have now -

```
function Nav(props) {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);
  const toggleSelected = () => setSelected(prevState => !prevState);
  return <div>
    <ul>
      <li className={!selected ? " not-selected" : " selected"} onClick={toggleSelected}>Item 1</li>
      <li className={!selected ? " not-selected" : " selected"} onClick={toggleSelected}>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>;
}
```

The problem with this though is when the state is changed it effects everything, not just the one item.

How can I make it specific to just one item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated:

Try to make list in map (with ids) and iterate over it ,then give a press event so,it will color that specific item.

i.e

```
NavItems.map(item => <li className={selected == item.id ? "green" : "red") onClick={()=>toggleSelected(item.id)}{item.name}</li>)
```

`and modify toggleSelected as`

```
const toggleSelected = (id) => setSelected(id);
```

Hope it will resolve your problem!

Comment: I put the items in an array and did this - 

    {navItems.map(function (name) {
      return <li className={!selected ? " not-selected" : " selected"}
        onClick={toggleSelected}
      >{name}</li>;
    })}

It's still changing the class for all the items though

It's still changing the class name for all the items

Comment: I have updated the ```Answer``` Recheck  and give upvote.. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have this Code Sandbox example that will help you to understand how to handlw different states for each item in a loop.

https://codesandbox.io/s/handling-states-example-with-data-fetching-w9m27